# Help deciding the number of components for PLSDA using mixomics

Tags: r, bioinformatics, partial-least-squares

I have a lipidomics dataset with more than 1800 features and 30 samples and I want to apply PLSDA. So, I used MixOmics to do this and here is my code:

```r
HLGA_plsda <- plsda(Normalized_data, Groups, ncomp = 10, 
                    scale = FALSE)  
perf_plsda <- perf(HLGA_plsda, validation = "Mfold", 
               folds = 3, nrepeat = 100,
               progressBar = TRUE, auc = TRUE)
plot(perf_plsda, col = color.mixo(5:7), sd = TRUE, 
     legend.position = "horizontal")
perf_plsda$choice.ncomp 
perf_plsda$error.rate
```

[image: Here is the plot]

Now, I get that only one component is the best with "$choice.ncomp", although I feel it is not reasonable and I should choose 2. Also how come I have a very low error rate, does it mean the model is over trained? or am I doing something wrong?
I chose not to scale because I get a higher classification error rate with scaling.

Also, using RVAideMemoire package, cross validation with 2 components gives me a lower classification error rate than one component:

```r
MVA.cv(Normalized_data, Groups, repet = 100, k = 3, ncomp = 1, 
       scale = FALSE, model ="PLS-DA")
```

And I get: Mean (standard error) classification error rate (%): 0.2 (0.08),
but with 2 components I get 0% (0)

So, I am really confused how to decide on the number of components, can anyone help? Both models with one or 2 components are significant upon permutation.

I am really new to this area so any advice will help!